# How to plot a list of figures in a single subplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, figure

I have 2 lists of figures and their axes.
I need to plot each figure in a single subplot so that the figures become in one big subplot. How can I do that?

I tried for loop but it didn't work.

Here's what I have tried:

```
import ruptures as rpt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# make random data with 100 samples and 9 columns 
n_samples, n_dims, sigma = 100, 9, 2
n_bkps = 4
signal, bkps = rpt.pw_constant(n_samples, n_dims, n_bkps, noise_std=sigma)

figs, axs = [], []
for i in range(signal.shape[1]):
    points = signal[:,i]
    # detection of change points 
    algo = rpt.Dynp(model='l2').fit(points)
    result = algo.predict(n_bkps=2)
    fig, ax = rpt.display(points, bkps, result, figsize=(15,3))
    figs.append(fig)
    axs.append(ax)
    plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] so it's easier to assist you. Do any of [these](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/index.html#subplots-axes-and-figures) examples help?

Comment: @importrandom Please check the question. I've added the code and rephrased my question. I've checked those examples, but none of them helps.

Comment: @Mr.T I want to extract the figures from the list and put them under each other in one subplot like this [link](https://i2.wp.com/raw.githubusercontent.com/conquistadorjd/python-03-matplotlib/master/subplot-11.png) for example

Comment: This is well-explained in the [matplotlib tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html). And in [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/markevery_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-markevery-demo-py), you see how to approach axes using a loop.  If you experience any specific problem related to your code, please ask another question.

Comment: @Mr.T That example is not quite what I'm looking for. In that example, the x and y are available and so it's easy to plot the figures using a for-loop. But in my case, I can't access the x or y because the figures are produced from a couple of libraries (i.e., heliopy and ruptures). I only have a list for the figures and another list for their corresponding axes options.

Comment: @Mr.T Yes exactly - It's so rigid with regard to dealing with the output figures, but I need to use it for detecting the time steps at which the data is changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the [source code of ruptures.display()](https://centre-borelli.github.io/ruptures-docs/code-reference/show/display/#ruptures.show.display.display), and it accepts **kwargs that are passed on to matplotlib. This allows us to redirect the output to a single figure, and with gridspec, we can position individual subplots within this figure:

```
import ruptures as rpt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_samples, n_dims, sigma = 100, 9, 2
n_bkps = 4
signal, bkps = rpt.pw_constant(n_samples, n_dims, n_bkps, noise_std=sigma)

#number of subplots
n_subpl = signal.shape[1]
#give figure a name to refer to it later
fig = plt.figure(num = "ruptures_figure", figsize=(8, 15))
#define grid of nrows x ncols
gs = fig.add_gridspec(n_subpl, 1)


for i in range(n_subpl):
    points = signal[:,i]
    algo = rpt.Dynp(model='l2').fit(points)
    result = algo.predict(n_bkps=2)
    #rpt.display(points, bkps, result)
    #plot into predefined figure
    _, curr_ax = rpt.display(points, bkps, result, num="ruptures_figure")
    #position current subplot within grid
    curr_ax[0].set_position(gs[i].get_position(fig))
    curr_ax[0].set_subplotspec(gs[i])   

plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. Thank you very much!